# Which activity tracker to get?

Tags: tracking, app

There is a plethora of options so I'm asking for help in choosing one, every time I search the web I'm lost in the number of search results. I want a tracker which will be best overall for tracking the things I personally care about. Those are:

1. Day-to-day activities - not actual exercises - like walking, climbing stairs, etc.
2. Sleep (with alarm, preferably smart alarm which will wake me during the appropriate phase but definitely before set time).
3. Cycling
4. Roller-blading
5. Gym/Weight lifting
6. Jogging
7. Swimming

Specs

- water resistant (down to 10 meters/30 feet)
- syncs with Android

As long as the tracker conforms to the above I don't care for form factor, stylishness, screen type (or even its existence).

Comment: You want a single tracker that does all that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shopping recommendations.

Comment: There is no product that does all this on the market now. Checkout DC rainmakers home page and blog. The closest "ecosystem" is probably Garmin, they will have an tracker for 1-2, have for 3, 4 (if considered as highpulse, position tracking), 6 and 7. The aerobic part of 5 should be covered by a pulsemeter + pen&paper with smartphone picture workout log. Suunto lacks support for 1-2 but have a rudimentary app ecosystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is asking a bit much!

Question is also a bit vague....

You need to specify how much you are prepared to spend, and what activities are the most important to you.

You won't find a gadget that will be really good at all of them.

However, the 2 that spring to mind are:-

A Fitbit - measures sleep and counts number of steps.  It comes with software, not sure if you could manually enter other activities?

A Garmin - will measure distance covered, and I believe if you get the right one you can use for bike and in the pool, jogging and non sport activities. It will record distance covered and pace. 
You can upload data to garmin software and manually input the rest.  However, it will not record sleep.